# Angular2 Model-driven form custom field validation from Observable API call

Tags: validation, angular, observable

I have an Angular 2 Model driven form that I am trying to do custom validation on a text field, which calls my API to verify that the name entered is unique.  However, I have tried about 20 different examples online and none of them work at all.

HTML:

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
var jQuery: any = require("jquery");
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

import { Tray } from '../../models/tray';

import { PartsService } from '../../services/parts.service';
import { PartsValidationService } from '../../validators/partsValidation.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'parts',
    styleUrls: ['../../../styles/main.css'],
    templateUrl: './partsForm.component.html',
    providers: [PartsService, SeriesService, PartsValidationService]
})

export class PartsFormComponent implements OnInit{
    trayForm: FormGroup;
    trayModalVisible: boolean;

    @ViewChild('trayModal') trayModal: ModalComponent;

    constructor(
        private partsService: PartsService,
        private partsValidationService: PartsValidationService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location,
        private router: Router,
        private http: Http,
        fb: FormBuilder
        ) {
        this.trayForm = fb.group({
            trayName: new FormControl('', Validators.required, partsValidationService.validate)           
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    openModal(modalName: any) {
        modalName.open();
    }

    closeModal(modalName: any) {
        modalName.close();
    }


    addTray() {
        debugger;
        this.partsService.saveTray(this.trayForm.value).subscribe(data => {
            this.closeModal(this.trayModal);
        });
    }    
}
```

Component:

```ts
    import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
    import { Location } from '@angular/common';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
    var jQuery: any = require("jquery");
    import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

    import { Tray } from '../../models/tray';

    import { PartsService } from '../../services/parts.service';
    import { PartsValidationService } from '../../validators/partsValidation.service';


    @Component({
        selector: 'parts',
        styleUrls: ['../../../styles/main.css'],
        templateUrl: './partsForm.component.html',
        providers: [PartsService, SeriesService, PartsValidationService]
    })

    export class PartsFormComponent implements OnInit{
        trayForm: FormGroup;
        trayModalVisible: boolean;

        @ViewChild('trayModal') trayModal: ModalComponent;

        constructor(
            private partsService: PartsService,
            private partsValidationService: PartsValidationService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private location: Location,
            private router: Router,
            private http: Http,
            fb: FormBuilder
            ) {
            this.trayForm = fb.group({
                trayName: new FormControl('', Validators.required, partsValidationService.validate)           
            });
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {

        }

        openModal(modalName: any) {
            modalName.open();
        }

        closeModal(modalName: any) {
            modalName.close();
        }


        addTray() {
            debugger;
            this.partsService.saveTray(this.trayForm.value).subscribe(data => {
                this.closeModal(this.trayModal);
            });
        }    
    }
```

Validation Service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Tray } from '../models/tray';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    validate(c: AbstractControl) {
        return this.getTrayByName(c.value);
    }

    getTrayByName(trayName:any) {
        return (trayName) => {
            this.http
                .get(`api/Parts/TrayByName/` + trayName)
                .map((response: any) => { return response.json() }).subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get an "Cannot read property 'getTrayByName' of undefined" error.  I have tried many other configurations, and nothing ever calls the API, but if I run the call in the browser or Fiddler, it calls the API fine.  I've spent a day and half on this what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, this is what ultimately got it working:

```
validateTrayName(c: FormControl) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.partsService.getTrayByName(c.value).subscribe(data => {
            if (data === null) {
                observer.next(null);
            } else {
                observer.next({ asyncInvalid: true });
            }
        });
    }).first().debounceTime(300);
}
```

With the following FormControl:

```
trayName: ['', [Validators.required], this.validateTrayName.bind(this)],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validator functions need to be just that - pure functions that accept a FormControl and return a boolean (either synchronously or asynchronously).

If you need to provide additional objects/parameters to allow your validator to do its job, then you basically have to have the function you pass to your FormControl be a function that returns a function.

Something like:

```
validateTrayName(http: Http) {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
          http
            .get(`api/Parts/TrayByName/` + c.value)
            .map((response: any) => { return response.json() });
    }
}
```

Where you pass in the Http service into your validateTrayName function and that returns a function that can use that Http service to validate.

And then in your component,

```
this.trayForm = fb.group({
                trayName: new FormControl('', Validators.required, this.validateTrayName(this.http))           
            });
```

or more simply,

```
this.trayForm = fb.group({
                trayName: ['', Validators.required, this.validateTrayName(this.http)]           
            });
```

where http and validateTrayName are properties of your component.
*(once you get the hang of it you can move things around to better fit your needs)*

**EDIT:**

My apologies - the previous version of this was not correct - the async value returned should be null for valid values, and a map of error types with their corresponding error messages if invalid.

So, you can chain another map onto the example above, but pay attention to the structure of the output:

```
validateTrayName(http: Http) {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
          http
            .get(`api/Parts/TrayByName/` + c.value)
            .map((response: any) => { return response.json() })
            .map(result => result.success ? null : { trayName: result.errorMsg });

}
```

The example above assumes that if the request is for a valid item, the response would be `{ success: true }`, and if invalid, it would be something like `{ success: false, errorMsg: 'this is not valid' }`

Comment: That results in "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined".

Comment: did you add http and validateTrayName as properties of your component containing the FormControl?

Comment: check out this plunk for an example of an async validator https://plnkr.co/edit/lzG6SP5PZK51JwLn9hbo?p=preview

Comment: Using the example in the plunk that snorkpete provided works... until I actually add my api call, then it throws an error that "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined".  Here's my validation function:

Comment: @KirbyKernen Did you solved it already? Having same issue here!

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel , no, I still don't have the validation working.

Answer (score 0):

```
validateTrayName() {
    return (control) =>
    {
        this.http.get(`api/Parts/TrayByName/` + control.value)
            .map((response: any) => { return response.json() }).subscribe(data => {
                if (data === null || control.value.length < 1) {
                    debugger;
                    return Observable.of({ nomatch: 'is invalid' });
                } else {
                    debugger;
                    return Observable.of(null);
                }
            });
    }
```

The example in the Plunk works, until you actually add in an http request.  Here's what I have now: